# Adding significance bars across facets of three-way interaction plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to represent the outcome of a GLMM with one response variable and three categorical predictors interacting with each other. From the anova of the model, it seems that the interaction of the three predictors has a significant effect on my response, so I proceeded to calculate the lsmeans of the response for each factor combination and created a graph in ggplot2. Since I have to represent **three factors**, I opted for a faceted plot.

The problem arose when I wanted to add significance bars, deriving from a post-hoc test, also across facets. I looked everywhere but I can only find solutions for graphs that include only two factors and not three. Here is what I would like to obtain, **being able to add the red lines across facets with code**:
[image: Three-way interaction plot]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found so far is quite laborious and made up of several different steps. It relies on the package *patchwork*, which allows us to embed images or other plots within an already-made plot. I took inspiration from jonspring's answer to a similar query on Posit Community (https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-can-i-connect-geom-vline-lines-across-facets-for-single-subject-design-plots/133160).

As first thing you create a dataset that contains the coordinates of the lines you want to draw. In patchwork, coodinates go from 0 to 1 both on the x axis (left to right) and on the y axis (bottom to top). It requires a bit of guesswork to figure out how to align precisely with the center of the dots of the graph.

```
segments <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(0,0.024,0.024, 1), # starting point of each significance line 
                                     y = c(0,0.89,0.96,1)), # y coordinates
                                     aes(x=x, y=y, xend=c(0,0.394,0.764,1),  # ending point of each significance line 
                                         yend=c(0,0.89 ,0.96,1))) + # y coordinates again
  geom_segment(size=0.4,color="red") +
  theme_void()

graph_RGR_22 + inset_element(
  segments, left = 0, bottom = 0, right = 1, top = 1)
```

The package patchwork is designed to insert **rectangular** objects on top of a plot, the arguments left, bottom, right and top specify the exact location of the edges of the object within the underlying plot (more details at https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/11/insetting-a-new-patchwork-version/). With `left = 0, bottom = 0, right = 1, top = 1`, I am free to use the whole plot area to insert lines.
The package sees a group of lines as if they were all contained in a single rectangle. To create boundaries for such rectangle,  and thus allow for free placement of each single line within it, I added 0 and 1 as respectively the first and last coordinate of x, y, xend and yend, so that I could use the entire area of my original plot as "canvas" (dotted red line in image below) to draw the significance bars across facets.

[image: Three-way interaction plot]

As long as on maintains 0s and 1s at the beginning and end of the data frame coordinates, one can add as many lines as necessary :)
I did not find yet a way to add the stars, so I added them manually.

I hope I was clear enough!